# SpringBootTest : Autowired Repositories are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test

I have a test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApplicationIntegrationTest {


@Autowired
MockMvc mvc;


@Autowired
MyRepository myRepository;

@Test
public void givenCourses() throws Exception{
    MyEntity entity = new Entity();
    myRepository.save(entity);

    mvc.perform(get("/someOperation")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content()
                    .contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}}
```

**MyRepository:**

```
@Repository
 public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {}
```

**MyEntity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder

public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=MYSQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test@123
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

spring.flyway.validateMigrationNaming= true
spring.flyway.locations= classpath:db/migration/h2

server.port=8082
```

When running test the Autowired myRepository is getting null. I have tried `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation but getting exception Cannot autowire myRepository `No qualifying bean of type MyRepository found`

Comment: version, stack trace, config details?

Comment: you can try with adding annotation @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) at class level

Comment: is the interface MyRepository placed in a location where the application finds it?

Comment: Can you try to add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`

Comment: @ODDminus1 Yes it is.

Comment: If you are running into problems with `@RunWIth(SpringRunner.class)` this indicates you are using the wrong `@Test` method (you should use the one from `org.junit.jupiter.api` not the `org.junit` one. The latter is for JUnit4 the former for JUnit5.

Answer (score 0):

The @Test annotation should be imported from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

If we use `org.junit.Test`, the test will use Junit 4 intead of Junit 5

Answer (score -1):

With your current test configuration, you limit the Spring auto configuration of your test application context to two classes: `Application` and `CorsConfig`.

By this means, no other auto configuration like the Spring `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is triggered, therefore no repository beans are ever going to be instantiated.

Just remove the `classes` property from the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, then it will work:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ApplicationIntegrationTest {
```

Without the `classes` property, Spring will create the whole application context for your test.